# Referencing Property file in Servlet Context

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

Newbies question:

I have in my Context XML

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:my_portal.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have the my_portal.properties file as part of my IntelliJ project (in /conf directory), however it seems that when I RUN/DEBUG the war_exploded artifact does not provide Tomcat the ability to access this file. How can I expose this file so that Tomcat can access it's properties inside the XML context files?

Answer (score 0):

The `classpath:` prefix means: look for this resource in the classpath. The classpath of a webapp is composed of the WEB-INF/classes directory, and of all the jars unders WEB-INF/lib.

So put the file in your source folder, and IntelliJ will "compile" it by copying it to the target folder, along with the compiled classes. Or change the IntelliJ project configuration to make it copy this file to WEB-INF/classes in the generated (exploded) war.

If you're using the Maven conventional layout, it should be under `src/main/resources`.